# Updating Query field condition Case or IF

Tags: sql, oracle

There's a field in my table called `Job Category`, I want to use `If` or `Case` statement to change the name of "Leader" within `job_category` to "senior Producer" and create a new field called `Job_category_New`. How do I go about doing that? Thanks.

Example:

```
update 'leader' category to 'senior producer'
case C.JOB_CATEGORY_1
     when C.JOB_CATEGORY_1 in ('Leader') then 'Senior Producer'
     else C.JOB_CATEGORY_1 as Job_Category_New
```

KW

Comment: Your question is quite hard to read, please try to clean it up a bit. It woudl also help to show current data and expected results, along with what you have tried and what was wrong with that. Do you actually mean you want to update the values stored in your table and add an extra column to the table; or is this just when querying the table and you want those changes in the result set?

Answer (score 1):

That's rather unclear; anyway, two options I managed to understand.

The first one updates current value of the `JOB_CATEGORY` column to 'senior producer' if its value is 'leader'. It leaves everything else intact. Also, using the `ALTER TABLE`, you can add a new column to the table.

```
update your_table set
  job_category = 'senior producer'
where job_category = 'leader';

alter table your_table add job_category_new varchar2(20);
```

---

The second one presumes that column already contains the JOB_CATEGORY_NEW column and updates both columns:

- job_category is set to 'senior producer' for all 'leaders' and to NULL for everything else
- job_category_new is set to current job_category column's value, except for 'leaders' (when it remains NULL)

.

```
update your_table set
  job_category     = decode(job_category, 'leader', 'senior producer', null),
  job_category_new = decode(job_category, 'leader', null, job_category);
```

See if it helps. If not, try to explain it once again, providing more details and examples.